# Looking for free pdf-viewer with similar annotation capabilities to Zotero

Tags: windows, gratis, chrome, pdf-viewer, annotation

This is what I require, anything else is optional: I must be able to set it as the default pdf-viewer, such that I can simply double-click on a file and start reading (Zotero can't do this, I have to start it first and open the files from the app). It must not copy the file to another directory automatically like Calibre does. Like Zotero, it must be able to highlight text in different colors, select areas form pages, comment them, add unattached comments, and tag all of the above, being able to show every highligh on a sidebar, without much clutter (as shown in the picture); and said highlights shouldn't be saved to the file unless I choose to do so, they must be saved on the program. It must be free forever, I don't mind if it's only a limited version of a more complete program as long as it has the same functionalities I've described, but I don't want free trials that will stop working after a while.

[image: Zotero's Annotations]

It doesn't need to read only PDFs, if it can also read and even do the same with other Ebook files that's a plus, but not required. I don't mind if it has many other functionalities either, while I was
looking for this I've found plenty PKM Software, and they all sound really interesting; in fact, I installed Obsidian because I thought I could use community plugins to annotate PDFs but, since I use Windows 7, it has a lot of compatibility issues and a lot of the plugins don't work.

Chrome extensions could also work, I've tried several and the best I've found are Memex and Hypothesis, obviously it has the problem that I need to open the file first in the browser and then click on the extentions to ask them to open the file again in their own viewers to be able to annotate, but I found a workaround: creating a batch file to directly open the extentions' viewers with the files I want to read, sadly it only works with Memex (which is a free trial extention), it doesn't work with Hypothesis since its anotation capabilities aren't active by default, I need to click on the taskbar icon to activate them and doing so while the viewer is open closes it. Still, if you know of any other free extension similar to these I could try them too.

I would be extremely grateful if you could help me; I only want to be able to read Ebooks the same way I read physical books, highlighting ideas I find interesting and adding comments on the margin related to them.